# ComponentDidMount is not working with this code

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

[ComponentDidMount is not working with this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUI8H.png)

when i check using react plugin in chrome don't get anything in array please help me to figure where i am wrong. i am little new in reactjs

Comment: lower case C instead of upper case

Comment: it worked thanks so much i appreciate your quick and accurate response #Martin.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think the negative response is mostly because you linked the code as image, rather than using a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).  It makes it much harder to review and/or copy to see where the issues might be.

Comment: that was my first question ever so for time saving i did that and also i am not familiar with posting code overhere but i must be careful for future to be good in posting question and code. anyways thanks alot.

Answer (score 4):

The [componentDidMount lifecycle function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) should start with a lowercase character, not uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using the life cycle events with stateful components and not functional components

Next, your life cycle definitions should defined before render()